# How to place numbers in a python list at the index of their magnitude

Tags: python, list

I have a sequence of random numbers placed in a python list:

```
[5,2,1,4,3]
```

I would like to place each number in a new `list` of same length according to the magnitude of the number, like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,5],[0,2,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,4,0],[0,0,3,0,0]]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  (The downvotes you are about to receive are because of the lack of effort you have put toward answering your own question)  see:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension along with a loop to fill in your list.

```
>>> max_len=max(l)
>>> new = [[0 for _ in range(max_len)] for _ in range(max_len)]
>>> for i,v in enumerate(l):
...     new[i][v-1] = v
... 
>>> new
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

Or you can use `numpy.zeros` within a list comprehension in one line :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l=[5,2,1,4,3]
>>> max_len=max(l)
>>> [[elem if elem-1==i else v for i,v in enumerate(arr)] for elem,arr in zip(l,[np.zeros(max_len) for _ in range(max_len)])]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5], [0.0, 2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 3, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I would like to correct my mistakes. Help me by making me understand the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [5,2,1,4,3] 
size = max(numbers)

results = []

for num in numbers:
    arr = [0] * size
    arr[num-1] = num
    results.append(arr)

print results

--output:--
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initial = [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
final = []
for x in initial:
    temp = [0 for i in range(len(initial))]
    temp[x-1] = x
    final.append(temp)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
tmp_lst = [] # The new list you want
lst = [5,2,1,4,3]
lst.sort() #Sort the list, so it become [1,2,3,4,5]
for i, num in enumerate(lst):
    tmp_lst.append([0]* len(lst)) #Adding a list of 0 the same lenght as your initial list
    tmp_lst[i][i] = num # Insert the value of your list at the right place
```

Answer (score -1):

- Create new List A
- Iterate existing list
- for each value, create a new list of that size
- populate new list
- add new list to list A